# How to call SQL Command with custom parameters in field (Crystal Reports)?

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports

I have a custom SQL expression with some parameters. 
I've added it to Field Explorer correctly. 
But I couldn't find an example of syntax for using  pre-defined parametrized SQL command with my own non-default parameters.
For example, there is a SQL expression like this (it's body of SQL command):

```
select count(*) from table A where A.col1 > {?param}
```

I want to create a set of fields with different parameters.
What should I to do?
Is it possible? 
Version of CR is 11, SQL syntax is Oracle SQL.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use parameter field in a SQL-expression field.

You can, however, use a parameter field with a Command object (assuming that the parameter was defined in the Command object)

Comment: Ok. Is it creating by "Add new SQL Command"? In case of true answer 
how should I insert to the report page result of my sql statement with predefined parameters?

Comment: To create a Command, go to Database Expert, click on your connection, choose "Add Command". Also see the Crystal Reports help section and look for Command Object. It has extensive knowledge and even step-by-step instructions.

Comment: However, I've already done it. Unfortunately, I didn't get how to create several instances of SQL Command with different parameters.

Comment: It's so unflexible... Thanks for advice.